# Infinite loop and dynamic content on slides

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my code, kinda trick where I only have one slide and I do the infinite loop with it and I want to change content dynamically. So it seems like i have multiple slides but actually it's one slide and content is taken dynamically from JSON

```
<ion-slides #originalslides class="top-slides" loop (ionSlidePrevEnd)="slideChanged( -1)" (ionSlideNextEnd)="slideChanged(1)" >
      <ion-slide> 
            <img  src="{{current}}">  
      </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>



slideChanged(step: number) {
    //calculate current step so you can take data from json
    this.slideStep = this.slideStep + step;
    this.current = this.data[this.slideStep];

}
```

The problem I'm having is that my content is being dynamically changed but not displayed in a slide. When I change my slide obviously it goes to the same slide because it's loop but my content is not displayed. Content is being displayed when I touch the slide/when I start to drag it.

How do I solve it?

Comment: I think you'll find the answer in the referenced post. Please let me know if that was not exactly what you were looking for. Thanks :)

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. This is more adding slides before and after than using only one slide and show content there. I have a problem with this because of videogular players, I can't dynamically add videos

Comment: I see... Ok, please let me know if that answer is not the right one for your scenario, and I'll reopen this question.

Comment: Let me just ask, does it pop/push slides in a way that when I slide to the next slide previous is destroyed and when I slide back current is destroyed (popped)?

Comment: Yes, the lines `this.numbers.pop();` and `this.numbers.shift();` are the ones that destroy the items after adding a new item to the array.

Comment: It might help, I need to check it out in more details. Thank you, I'll let you know if I can modify it to my needs and I'll post my code here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154262/discussion-between-fosavance-and-sebaferreras).